# Transformation of entropy

Tags: information-theory

Let $X$ be a discrete random variable with values $A = \{+1,+2,+4,+8\}$, such that that entropy $H(X) = 2$ bits.

For $Y=\log_2(X)$, such that $Y\in\{+0,+1,+2,+3\}$, we find that

- $P(Y = +0) = P(Y = +3) = 0$
- $P(Y = +1) = P(Y = +2) = \frac{1}{2}$

Is this right?

Second question: **prove that there is no such function $g$ such that $H(g(X)) > H(X)$.**

I think we should start off by assuming $g$ exists and $H(g(X)) > H(X)$, then prove by absurdity that this is impossible by stating the Gibbs inequality, such that
$$\sum_{i=1}^4 p_i \log_2\frac{q_i}{p_i} \leq 0$$
with $p_i$ the probabilities of $X$ and $q_i$ the probabilities of $g(X)$.
I'm not sure how to make use of this inequality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. First you need to show $P(X=a)=\frac{1}{4}$ for any $a=1, 2, 4, 8$. There is a simple idea behind the scene: Since there are four possible outcomes of $X$, we only need two bits to encode $X$, hence its entropy is at most $2$, and it's well-known that for discrete variables, this upper bound can only achieved by a uniform distribution.

Rigorously, $H(X)=\sum_a p_a\log_2 \frac{1}{p_a}\le \log_2(\sum_a \frac{p_a}{p_a})=\log_24=2$ by the convexity of $\log_2$, and the equality holds iff $p_a:=P(X=a)$ are all the same. To be completely rigorous, we may have to worry about $p_a=0$ for some $a$, in which case ignoring those terms and still apply the convexity, we get $H(X)\le \log_2(3)<2$.

Now $P(Y=a)=P(X=2^a)=\frac{1}{4}$.

As for the second part, intuitively, if we can transmit $X$ with $n$-bits on average, then we can transmit $g(X)$ with at most $n$-bits, since the receiver can call the function $g$ by herself to get $g(X)$ once $X$ is known , hence $H(g(X))\le H(X)$. A rigorous proof is not harder either:

$$H(g(x))=\sum_a P(g(x)=a)\log_2 \frac{1}{P(g(x)=a)}=-\sum_aP(x\in g^{-1}(a))\log_2(P(x\in g^{-1}(a)))$$

And because $\log_2$ is monotone, $$\begin{aligned} P(x\in g^{-1}(a))\log_2P(x\in g^{-1}(a)) &=(\sum_{b\in g^{-1}(a)}P(x=b))\log_2(\sum_{b\in g^{-1}(a)}P(x=b)) \\ &\ge\sum_{b}P(x=b)\log_2(P(x=b)) \end{aligned}$$

This also follows from some more advanced inequality from information theory, but it's really just elementary calculus.

Comment: If I understand correctly, $P(Y=a)=P(X=2^a)$ because $\log_2$ is strictly monotone, right? Shouldn't this be independent of the fact that $X$ distribution is uniform?

Comment: So if I were to define $f(x) = x \mod 2$, the probabilities of $f(X)$ should be $P(f(X) = 0) = P(X = 2) + P(X = 4) + P(X = 8) = \frac{3}{4}$ and $P(f(X) = 1) = P(X = 1) = \frac{1}{4}$?

Comment: For $P(Y=a)=P(X=2^a)$, we only need $\log_2$ is injective, so no two different values of $X$ are mapped to the same $Y$. This is indeed independent of $X$ is uniform. You're right about the $X\mod 2$.

Answer (score 1):

For the second part: let $Y=g(X)$. We know $H(Y|X)=0$ (because knowing $X$ we know $Y$)

We also know the chain rule: $H(X,Y)=H(X)+H(Y|X)=H(Y)+H(X|Y)$

Hence, in our case $H(Y)= H(X)-H(X|Y)$. Because $H(X|Y)\ge 0$, we conclude

$$H(Y)=H(g(X)) \le H(X)$$

Comment: So for a general rule, once $Y$ is defined as $f(X)$ (with no assumptions if $f$ is bijective or not), we can write $H(Y|X) = 0$ and $H(X|Y)\geq 0$?

Comment: Yes, the first equality is becaue of $Y=f(X)$ (deterministic well defined function). The second one is a general property: the entropy (conditioned or not) is always non-negative. Further, if the function is invertible then the symmetric $H(X|Y)=0$ would hold.